# Group days in Business Objects?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I'm trying to group StartDateTime in Business Objects. Data for StartDateTime is coming from a Cisco server. It is in format 7/15/2013 10:52 AM. I am just trying to group these so it's 7/1, 7/2, etc.

I need to create a dimension out of this Day Grouping so I can represent a count of events on each date. Right now I am doing:

```
=FormatDate([Query 1 (1)].[Startdatetime];"DD")
```

I've tried variations of this, but nothing is working. I used the above formula to group the hours, I just replaced "DD" with "HH", so not sure why this formula would be so different.

Any ideas? Thank you. It's appreciated.

Comment: Is the date field stored in the database as a native Date, or as a character string?  Is modifying the universe a possibility for you?

Answer (score 0):

what if you try

=FormatDate([Query 1 (1)].[Startdatetime];"dd/MM/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

This is old but wasn't answered. In case anyone stumbles upon this like I just did, the formula is just case sensitive. It should be:

```
=FormatDate([Query 1 (1)].[Startdatetime];"MM/dd")
```

Here's a link that includes all permutations of date formatting: 
https://blogs.sap.com/2013/11/21/how-to-use-formulae-to-change-date-and-time-formats-in-webintelligence/